# 'Could not build module' when importing Google Places / Google Maps - iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, import, frameworks

I would like to know how I can import these google frameworks (GoogleMaps, GooglePlacePicker, GooglePlaces).

I have tried setting "Allow Non Modular Includes = YES", "Allow Modules Objective C = YES", and "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code = YES".... but am still receiving the same error.

When I @import CoreLocation or any other framework, I do not receive this error. It only shows up for the Google frameworks.

Thank you for any help.

SCREENSHOT OF ERROR